# error: invalid types 'double[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, array

estoy aprendiendo c++, y no se como solucionar el error de este código,adjunto el enunciado del ejercicio para contexto, me da error a la hora de usar los arrays en el bucle for, supongo que no es por el bucle y se que es por un error mio pero desconozco cual, porque en sí al ejecutar el código me dan 6 errores, que son mayormente el mismo.

[image: enunciado del ejercicio]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Vector3d
{
    private:
    float v;

    public:
    Vector3d()
    {
        vector<float> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    }
    ~Vector3d()=default;

    Vector3d& escalado(double esca )
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            v[i]=esca*v[i];
        }
        return v[i];
    }

    Vector3d& magnitud()
    {
        int i,raiz;
        float mag;
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            raiz=raiz+v[i];
        }
        mag=sqrt(raiz);
        return mag;
    }
};

int main()
{
    float v;
    cout << "dame los valores de un vector de 6 componentes" << endl;
    cin >> v(6);
}
```

Comment: Podrias poner el error que te da?

Comment: error: invalid types 'float[int]' for array subscript en las lineas 23 23 y 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En este constructor:

```
Vector3d()
{
    vector<float> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
}
```

Estás creando una variable local, que casualmente se llama igual que su variable miembro, pero son variables diferentes. Esta variable local será finalmente un vector con 6 datos de tipo `float`. Desgraciadamente, al ser una variable local, en cuando la ejecución abandone el constructor la variable desaparecerá.

Lo primero que podríamos pensar es en no declarar una nueva variable sino en usar la variable miembro:

```
Vector3d()
{
    v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
}
```

Pero esto nos va a fallar porque has declarado la variable miembro `v` como un dato de tipo `float` en vez de como un vector de floats. La solución es igualmente simple:

```
class Vector3d
{
    private:
    std::vector<float> v;
```

Pero aún podríamos mejorar este código:

```
Vector3d()
    : v{1,2,3,4,5,6}
{
}
```

En  el primer caso que te he puesto:

```
Vector3d()
{
    v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
}
```

Lo que sucede a nivel interno es que primero se invocará al constructor por defecto de `v` y, después, se intentará invocar a algún operador de asignación que sea capaz de recibir una `std::initializer_list`. Son demasiadas operaciones, lo razonable sería invocar directamente al constructor que nos interesa, y eso se consigue de la forma que te he mostrado:

```
Vector3d()
    : v{1,2,3,4,5,6}
{
}
```

Como ahora la variable miembro es de tipo `vector<float>`, podrás invocar sin problemas los operadores de indexación `[]` así como otras funciones propias de `std::vector`

Comment: okey, muchas gracias

Comment: Si ves que la respuesta ha solucionado tu duda, puedes marcar el tic que la acompaña. Así todo el que entre sabrá que esa respuesta fue útil y respondía a la duda. ;-)